# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STANDARD_IMPORTS

Tags: java, linux

I've restarted server and I can't get it to run. I always get this error when starting. Please can someone tell me how to get the server to run?

I've searched and I can't find this error anywhere else.

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

STANDARD_IMPORTS
RequestURI=/

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STANDARD_IMPORTS
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.(PageInfo.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:367)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:890)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:756)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:367)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:285)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:502)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:821)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:208)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:378)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:226)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

This was after a server restart

Comment: You not even name the server or show us your application? How do you think anyone could help you? The exception says that you have a problem with a Jasper template.

Comment: The application is huge! Hmm I didn't think we used Jasper.  I'm trying to find someone who knows what a STANDARD_IMPORTS
RequestURI=/ is

Comment: I think you used Jasper: `at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.(PageInfo.java:100)`...

Answer (score 0):

I removed Jasper from the libraries and the problem seems to have gone away for now